# Returning HTML image if user is logged in

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to prevent anonymous user to directly access JPG files (but allow for thumbnails).  I did a .htaccess to protect my JPG files:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<FilesMatch "resize\.jpg|0\.jpg">
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And simply do this:

```
  if( isLogged() )
  {
    $imageName = $_GET['image'];
    $imageFile = "/pathToFile/{$imageName}.jpg";

    if( file_exists( $imageFile ) ) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        readfile($imageFile);
        exit;
    }
  }
```

Problem is, to look if user is logged in, I need to do a session_start(), which prevents me to to set correctly the headers of the response.  But the whole point is to check if the user is logged in before returning the file.  Any idea?

Comment: You've got a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Have to call ob_start() before session_start() and use ob_clean() if I want to send the pics.